# ¿Query dinamico?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo el siguiente query:

```
select CONCAT('PtdBal',(select right(substring(PerNbr,5,2)-1+100,2) from SLApplication.dbo.GLSetup)) 
       from SLApplication.dbo.AcctHist 
       where substring(Sub, 16, 6) = '189621' 
       and acct like '822%733%' 
       and PtdBal05 < 0  
       and fiscYr =  (select substring(PerNbr, 1, 4) from SLApplication.dbo.GLSetup) 
       and LedgerID = '02'
```

El cual me arroja el siguiente resultado:

```
    | (sin nombre de columna)
----|------------------------
  1 |   PtdBal05
```

Pero resulta que `PtdBal05` es el nombre de la columna. ¿Como puedo obtener el/los registros que tiene la columna? ¿Se puede hacer esto en el query sin usar un Store Procedure o forzosamente tengo que usar un Store Procedure? Preferiría que se pueda hacer esto en el query.¿Esto es un query dinamico?
Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: En el resultado de tu consulta, ¿es posible obtener el nombre de la tabla?

Comment: la tabla es esta `SLApplication.dbo.AcctHist` siempre, lo que es dinamico es el campo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suponiendo que el resultado de tu consulta te regresa un nombre de alguna columna y la tabla siempre es `SLApplication.dbo.AcctHist`, y además el resultado se genera con el `Id = 1`, entonces propongo la siguiente consulta dinámica:

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(1000)
DECLARE @columna varchar(75)

SELECT TOP 1
    @columna = Columna
FROM 
(
    SELECT CONCAT (
        'PtdBal'
        ,(
            SELECT right(substring(PerNbr, 5, 2) - 1 + 100, 2)
            FROM SLApplication.dbo.GLSetup
            )
        ) AS Columna
    FROM SLApplication.dbo.AcctHist
    WHERE substring(Sub, 16, 6) = '189621'
        AND acct LIKE '822%733%'
        AND PtdBal05 < 0
        AND fiscYr = (
            SELECT substring(PerNbr, 1, 4)
            FROM SLApplication.dbo.GLSetup
            )
        AND LedgerID = '02'
) AS T

SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT ' + @Columna + ' FROM SLApplication.dbo.AcctHist'
EXEC (@sqlCommand)
```

Donde en la variable `@columna = Columna` se guarda el nombre del campo, para que posteriormente se ejecute la consulta dinámica.

Answer (score 0):

Al final quedo asi:

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(1000)
DECLARE @columna varchar(75)
SELECT TOP 1 @columna = Columna FROM (
    select CONCAT('PtdBal',(
                            select right(substring(PerNbr,5,2)-1+100,2) 
                            from SLApplication.dbo.GLSetup
                           )
                 ) AS Columna 
    from SLApplication.dbo.AcctHist 
) AS T
SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT ' + @columna + ' FROM SLApplication.dbo.AcctHist 
                   where substring(Sub, 16, 6) = ''189621''
                   AND acct LIKE ''822%733%''
                   AND PtdBal05 < 0
                   AND fiscYr = (
                         SELECT substring(PerNbr, 1, 4)
                         FROM SLApplication.dbo.GLSetup
                                )
                   AND LedgerID = ''02''
'
EXEC (@sqlCommand)
```

Gracias