# ¿como puedo hacer reproducir mi lista de canciones en el listview?

Tags: java, android-studio

Hola estoy realizando una lista de canciones que tengo guardado en la carpeta raw
pero no se como hacer para que mis canciones se reproduzcan en el ListView.
aparecen el nombre de las canciones pero al momento de tocarlo no lo reproduce,

por favor le agrade seria una ayuda, les dejo el codigo para que me corrijan.

este es el activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listaCanciones;
Button play_pause;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    play_pause = (Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
    listaCanciones = findViewById(R.id.lista);
    registerForContextMenu(listaCanciones);

     listaCanciones.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,servicio.class));
        }
    });
    play_pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,servicio.class));
        }
    });
    Button detener=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    detener.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,servicio.class));
        }
    });
```

}
}

y este el servicio

```
 public class servicio extends Service {
    MediaPlayer reproductor;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Servicio Creado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    reproductor= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.maluma);
}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    reproductor.setVolume(0.01f, 0.1f);
    reproductor.start();
    return START_STICKY;
}
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    reproductor.stop();
}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: Y el `mp.start()`???

Comment: ahi lo agregue, es esa?

Comment: ` int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(list.get(i), "raw", getPackageName());
                    
                    mp.start();
                    play_pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Reproduciendo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();´

Comment: Eso nunca se ejecuta porque `mp` es null. Mejor mira este ejemplo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/291813/3834

Comment: Ah ya voy entendiendote mejor, y como hago para que se ejecute desde mi listview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un listView tiene un método el cual se invoca cuando haces clic en un item. Dentro de ese método tienes que lanzar el servicio donde esta la música haciendo un intent. Es algo así:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
        startService(new Intent(ActividadPrincipal.this,ServicioMusica.class));
    }
});
```

Para que sepas mejor que es lo que contienen las clases ActividadPrincipal y ServicioMusica revisa este [enlace](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/291813/3834). Ojo, tienes que hacer pruebas, no poseo un ejemplo exactamente como deseas pero es la combinación de este código con el del hilo que te pongo. Tal vez la clase ActividadPrincipal cambie por la activity donde esta declarada la listView y los métodos de ActividadPrincipal no sean necesarios, sino que hay que lanzar el servicio desde `setOnItemClickListener`. Pero esa es la idea principal.

Answer (score 0):

ya me funciono perfectamente el reproductor gracias a la ayuda de @abrahamhs

aqui les dejo el activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


ListView listaCanciones;
List<String> list;
ListAdapter adapter;

MediaPlayer mp;

int posicion = 0;
Button play_pause, btn_repetir;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    play_pause = (Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
    listaCanciones = findViewById(R.id.lista);

    list = new ArrayList<>();

    Field[] fields = R.raw.class.getFields();
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){
        list.add(fields[i].getName());
    }


    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.list_view_configuracion, list);
    listaCanciones.setAdapter(adapter);

    listaCanciones.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            if(mp != null ){
                mp.stop();
                mp.release();
            }



            int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(list.get(i), "raw", getPackageName());
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, resID);
            mp.start();
            play_pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground);

        }
    });

}

public void play_pause(View view){
    if (mp.isPlaying()){
        mp.pause();
        play_pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground);

    }
    else {
        mp.start();
        play_pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);

    }
}
```

}

abajo iria el metodo play y todos los metodos que le quieran agregar. espero que le sirvan.

Comment: [Si ya te funciona gracias a mi ayuda ¿Porque me quitas los puntos de la respuesta aceptada? Debe quedar como en este ejemplo.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/47105/3834)